# Pullback of diffrential forms in surjective submersions

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, and suppose $P:M\to N$ is a surjective smooth submersion with connected fibers. Show that given $\alpha \in \Omega^k(M)$ there exists $\beta\in \Omega^k(N)$ such that $\alpha=P^*\beta$ if and only if $\iota_X \alpha=0$ and $L_X \alpha =0$ for every $X \in \ker(dP)$.

**Solution**

Let $\alpha=P^*\beta$, so by definition of pullback we have that:
        \begin{align}
   \alpha_x(X)=\beta_{P(x)}(dP(X))
  \end{align} for $x \in M$ and $X\in T_xM$\
        If we take $X$ such that $X\in \ker(dP)$, then $\iota_X \alpha = 0$.

To prove that $L_X \alpha =0$, we will use Cartan's magic formula:
    \begin{align}
   L_X\alpha= \iota_X d\alpha +d(\iota_X \alpha) 
  \end{align}
        We already have that the second term is zero for $X\in ker(dP)$.\
        Using the fact that $d(P^*\beta)=P^*d\beta$, and the definition of pullback we get that the first term in Cartan's formula becomes $d\beta_{P(x)}(dP(X))=0$ if $X\in \ker(dP)$.

Thus we have that $L_X \alpha =0$ for all $X\in \ker(dP)$.

Conversely, let us define the pullback in terms of local coordinates with $P:M\to N$ as $P(x_1,...,x_n,...,x_m)=(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Given $\alpha \in \Omega^k(M)$, we can write it as 
        \begin{align}
   \alpha = \sum_{1}^{m}f_I(x_1,...,x_m) dx_I
  \end{align}
        for $I=(x_1,...,x_m)$. By hypothesis, $\iota_X \alpha =0$ for all $X\in \ker(dP)$. By the way we defined the pullback, the expression $X\in \ker(dP)$ means that $X=c_iX_i$, where $X_i=0$ for $n<i\leq m$.

The second condition $L_X \alpha =0$, with cartan's formula and the first condition means that $\iota_X d\alpha=0$. Replacing we get:
        \begin{align}
  d\alpha = \sum_{I,j}^{m}\dfrac{f_I(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial(x_i)}dx_j\wedge dx_I
  \end{align}
        Evaluating on $X\in \ker(dP)$, we get that the change of $f_I$ in the direction of $x_i$ is zero for $n<i\leq m$. Then our conditions on alpha means that $f_I(x_1, ...,x_m)= f_I(x_1,...,x_n,0,...,0)$ for all $X\in \ker(dP)$.

Let $g_J= f_I\circ P$, so we have that:
        \begin{align}
   P^*\alpha = \sum_{I}^{m} f_I\circ P(x_1,...,x_m) dx_I=\sum_{J}^{n} g_J(x_1,...,x_n) dx_J=\beta
  \end{align}
Thus completing the proof.

I want to check this proof as I am not confident on the second part. I think I am missing something on how the $dx_i$ with $n<i\leq m$ dissappear. Also I think I am messing something up with the indices but I can't say what exactly.
My professor explained me the main idea of the second part of the proof. I think I understand the general idea, but not enough to put it in rigorous terms.

Comment: This result is false. Here's a counterexample.
Let $P\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb S^1$ be the map $P(x,y) = (\cos x, \sin x)$, and let $\alpha=x\, dx$ on $\mathbb R^2$. A vector field on $\mathbb R^2$ is in the kernel of $dP$ at each point if and only if it is of the form $X = f(x,y) \partial/\partial y$ for some function $f$.  For any such $X$, we have $i_X\alpha = 0$ and $\mathscr L_X\alpha = d(i_X\alpha) + i_X(d\alpha) = 0$. However, there is no $1$-form on $\mathbb S^1$ whose pullback is equal to $\alpha$.
You need to add the additional hypothesis that the fibers of $P$ are connected.

Comment: You are right. That hypothesis is missing

Comment: What are $\iota_X$ and $L_X$?

Comment: $i_x \omega$ is the contraction of $\omega$ with respect to the vector field $X$. And $L_X$ is the lie derivative with respect to $X$

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look so good to me. We don't necessarily have $k=1$. Let's organize ourselves:

- If $\alpha = P^*\beta$, then $X \in \ker {\rm d}P \require{cancel}$ says that $$\iota_X\alpha(X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}) = \alpha(X,X_1,\ldots,X_k) = \beta(\cancelto{0}{{\rm d}P(X)},{\rm d}P(X_1),\ldots, {\rm d}P(X_{k-1})) = 0,$$so $\iota_X\alpha=0$. Also, we have that $$\begin{align} \mathcal{L}_X\alpha(X_1,\ldots,X_k) &= X(\alpha(X_1,\ldots,X_k)) - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha(X_1,\ldots,[X,X_i],\ldots, X_k) \\ &= X(\beta({\rm d}P(X_1),\ldots, {\rm d}P(X_k))) - \sum_{i=1}^n \beta({\rm d}P(X_1),\ldots,{\rm d}P([X,X_i]),\ldots, {\rm d}P(X_k)) \\ &= \cancelto{0}{X(\beta({\rm d}P(X_1),\ldots, {\rm d}P(X_k)))} - \sum_{i=1}^n \beta({\rm d}P(X_1),\ldots,[\cancelto{0}{{\rm d}P(X)},{\rm d}P(X_i)]),\ldots, {\rm d}P(X_k))\\ &= 0.\end{align}$$
- Assume $\iota_X\alpha=0$ and $\mathcal{L}_X\alpha=0$ for all $X \in \ker {\rm d}P$. I don't have much time to go over all details now, but here's the idea: define $\beta$ locally using the charts given by the constant rank theorem -- $\mathcal{L}_X\alpha=0$ will allow us to define $\beta$ along the whole chart around $P(x)$ in $N$ via the flows of the vector fields $\partial_i$, with $n+1 \leq i \leq m$, since $(\mathcal{L}_{\partial_i}\alpha)_{i_1\cdots i_k} = \partial \alpha_{i_1 \cdots i_k}/\partial x^i$ (which you seem to have done, when writing $g_{i_1 \cdots i_k}(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0\ldots,0)$), and the condition $\iota_X\alpha=0$ will say that the resulting $\beta$ is well-defined (it is not clear to me what you mean by $c_iX_i$, are you missing a sum?).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been going through your answer carefully. On the first part of the proof I don't understand why is $X(\beta(dP(X_1),...,dP(X_k)))=0$ 
I am still going through the second part. You are right I am missing a sum. By $c_iX_i$, I meant $X = \sum^n X_i \partial_i$. I don't understand how the condition $\iota_X \alpha=0$ makes $\beta$ well defined

Comment: Recall that if $F\colon M \to N$ is smooth, then ${\rm d}F_p(X_p)(g) = X_p(g\circ F)$, and then $X \in \ker {\rm d}P$ means that ${\rm d}P(X)(g) = X(g\circ P)=0$, with $g$ being the map $p\mapsto \beta_{P(p)}({\rm d}P_p(X_1(p)),\ldots, {\rm d}P_p(X_k(p)))$. About $\iota_X\alpha=0$, roughly the idea is that given $q \in N$, you could have $p_1,p_2 \in M$ with $P(p_1)=P(p_2)=q$. If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are in the same chart, you could map one point to the other with the flow of some field in $\ker {\rm d}P$ (some combination of the last coordinate vector fields).

Comment: There is one thing I don't get when using $dP(X)(g)=X(g\circ P)=0$. Shouldn't $g$ be $g:N \to \mathbb{R}$, so that $g \circ P: M \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X$ could act on it? Because with the map $g$ you wrote that would be $g:M \to \mathbb{R}$. I tried to fix it by using $g:N\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(q):= \beta_q(dP_{P^{-1}(q)}(X_1(P^{-1}(q)), ..., dP_{P^{-1}(q)}(X_1(P^{-1}(q)))$ but as $P$ is not a bijection $P^{-1}(q)$ would be a set instead of a point.

Comment: (cont.) Is there a way to prove there exists $g:N\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g\circ P(p)=\beta_{P(p)}(dP_p(X_1(p)),...,dP_p(X_k(p))$

Comment: For the second part, I thought that the condition $\mathcal{L}_X\alpha =0$ meant that $f_I$ did not change in the directions $\partial_i$ for $n+a\leq i \leq m$. And that the condition $\iota_X \alpha=0$ meant that $f_I=0$ in the directions $\partial_i$ for $n+a\leq i \leq m$. Is this reasoning corect? Also the result that given $p_1,p_2 in M$ with $P(p_1)=P(p_2)=q$ , one could map one point to the other,be a result of the connected fibers of P?